# Added field to report causes report not to be shown

Tags: ms-access

I need to perform a small change to a report running on an old version of MS-Access (2007). The report is based on a simple `SELECT` statement which, when running it directly vis-à-vis the DB (SQL Server Management Studio) it generates the required data.

A new field needs to be added to the same report and hence the original query was updated to include the new field. Again, execution of the query vis-à-vis the database yields the desired result (including the new field of course).

The new query was deployed into the report (replacing the old one).

Now, I added a new element to the report and set the source of its value to be the new (added) field, which appears in the list of available sources.

The problem is:

- When I set the new field as the source of the added object, the report is not generated at all (no error messages are shown either),
- If I leave the source of the field as blank, the report is generated (though the new element is shown empty of course),
- If I set as the source of the new element any other field shown in the list, the report is generated and the value of the field is being shown correctly.

Can anyone suggest how and where to search for the issue? For instance, try to breakpoint at the opening of the report (if that part of the code is accessible at all).

Unfortunately, I cannot share code nor screenshots (company policy).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to rename the newly added textbox.

Comment: Already tried that with. Didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Then rebuild the report.

Comment: Thank you @Gustav. I had some progress though... While examining the code, I found that its developer (long ago left the company) deployed plenty of `On Error Resume Next` and hence there was no feedback. After commenting that statement, I receive an error message stating that `Column (myCol) does not exist in the appropriate rowset`. How do I search for the location where the new field needs to be added as well (i.e. the expected rowset)?

Comment: OK, that explains. You will have to look in the query (or SQL statement) that drives the report, or to adjust the code to not use that column. Hard to be more specific with zero code.

Comment: @Gustav I understand the limitations and appreciate your support. One more question if I may: After updating the query (i.e. adding the new field), when editing the report you can select the source of the data for the new (say) textbox. In my case, the new field **IS SHOWN** in the drop-menu of all available sources (and hence is **known and within the scope**. Apparently, the issue is with the structure that **RECEIVES** the record. When can I find the definition of that structure? Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: I would say there is no receiving structure. You add controls as you like and bind fields or expressions to these. But your code may do nasty things when opening and running the report.

Comment: @Gustav, yes, I understood it after a couple of hours examining this project for the first time (also first time with Access ever). And, I must correct you: it isn't my code (if it was, I would be considering a change of occupation). The thing is that the error appears upon `DoCmd.OpenReport` and the events related to the report do nothing with the data. So, I'm quite lost to be frank...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130705/discussion-between-gustav-and-fdavidov).

Comment: @Gustav, I'll only be back with access to the system on Monday. If OK will you, we'll continue then (will signal you when connected).

Comment: @Gustav, eventually, I got access to the project today. Just wanted to update you that I tried the documented method to add a field to the report (i.e. display the fields list and drag the desired field to the report) and this still triggers the same error.

Comment: Try creating a new report with only the id of the record and this field.

Comment: Hello @Gustav and thanks for your recommendation. Yesterday (quite late) I found the issue: Whoever developed the report, implemented a number of overrides to its basic query. Once I added the new field to all the relevant overrides, the error disappeared and the new fields started to show in the report. Yes, I know, I think the same about the original developer of the report, and unfortunately she is no longer in the company to share with her my thoughts. Anyway, I truly appreciate your support (and up-voted some of your comments as a gesture of gratitude). Wish you a great day!!

Comment: Ah, the hidden secrets. It demonstrates how important it is to document the code, indeed when you perform not so obvious "smart" tricks.